# How to display values from two separate tables from mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am trying to view values from two separate tables using a foreach loop. The user chooses a "Start semester" and an "End semester" from a drop down list, and those two semesters are stored into an array called $semesterarray

```
<table style='width: 75%; text-align: left;' cellpadding = '4'>
<tr bgcolor=#000090>
<th><FONT COLOR = #FFFFFF><b><?php echo $startsem ?></b></th>
<th><FONT COLOR = #FFFFFF><b><?php echo $endsem ?></b></th>
</tr>

// If $semesterarray contains 10 and 11, I want to be able to view the
// courses taken in the 10 semester and the 11 semester under two separate columns.

<?php
function getSemesterDetails($semester) 
{
    $output = "";
    $semA = $semester."reg";
    $query = "SELECT course1,course2,course3 FROM $semA";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

            // row displays: [course1]=> [course2]=> [course3]=>

            // Add semester code to array Keys to indicate proper semester
            // [course1.11]=> [course2.11]=> [course3.11]=>

            foreach ($row as $key => $value)
            {
                $row[$key.".".$semester] = $value;
                unset($row[$key]);
            }

        $startcourse1 = $row['course1.'.$semester];
        $startcourse2 = $row['course2.'.$semester];
        $startcourse3 = $row['course3.'.$semester];
        $startcoursesarray = array($startcourse1, $startcourse2, $startcourse3);
        $startcourses = implode("<br>", $startcoursesarray);

        $endcourse1 = $row['course1.'.$semester];
        $endcourse2 = $row['course2.'.$semester];
        $endcourse3 = $row['course3.'.$semester];
        $endcoursesarray = array($endcourse1, $endcourse2, $endcourse3);
        $endcourses = implode("<br>", $endcoursesarray);

        echo "<tr bgcolor=#ABB5F6>
        <td>$startcourses</td>
        <td>$endcourses</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}

foreach ($midsemarrayA as $key => $semester)
{
echo getSemesterDetails($semA);
}

?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: With the above code, I can only view the courses taken in the "10" semester. This is because the echo statement at the bottom is occurring for the first iteration of the foreach loop. Is there a working method to loop through and view the courses taken in the "11" semester as well?

The "10" semester and "11" semester are two separate tables in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough for you to make a start:

```
function getSemesterDetails ($semester) {
    $output = "";

    $query = "SELECT course1,course2,course3 FROM $semester";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            // row displays: [course1]=> [course2]=> [course3]=>

            // Add semester code to array Keys to indicate proper semester
            // [course1.11]=> [course2.11]=> [course3.11]=>

            foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                $row[$key.".".$semester] = $value;
                unset($row[$key]);
            }

        $startcourse1 = $row['course1.'.$semester];
        $startcourse2 = $row['course2.'.$semester];
        $startcourse3 = $row['course3.'.$semester];
        $startcoursesarray = array($startcourse1, $startcourse2, $startcourse3);
        $startcourses = implode("<br>", $startcoursesarray);

        $endcourse1 = $row['course1.'.$semester];
        $endcourse2 = $row['course2.'.$semester];
        $endcourse3 = $row['course3.'.$semester];
        $endcoursesarray = array($endcourse1, $endcourse2, $endcourse3);
        $endcourses = implode("<br>", $endcoursesarray);

        $output .= "<tr bgcolor=#ABB5F6>
        <td>$startcourses</td>
        <td>$endcourses</td>
        </tr>";
    }

return $output;
}

foreach ($semesterarray as $key => $semester) {
     getSemesterDetails($semester);
}
```

You'll want to get it to return an array of values rather than a string, but shifting it into a subroutine should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This doesn't seem to display values on my table.

Comment: You'll need to echo the output from the function call; or just switch the `$output .= "` back to `echo "`

Comment: How can I obtain $semester from $semesterarray without using a loop in this case?

Comment: You can still use the `foreach` in your code to generate $key and $semester; you'll just need a call to getSemesterDetails inside the loop

Comment: I edited my code above like so but it still only displays values for the 10 semester, not the 11.

Comment: I've tweaked my answer a little